# Can't use ALT-TAB to switch between windows

Tags: application-switcher

ALT-TAB used to work in unity on my Ubuntu 12.04 desktop. I installed gnome-session-fallback and logined using gnome classic. Now this key combination doesn't work any more.

I checked ccsm, in the "Windows Management", I do have "Static Application Switcher" enabled,  binding tab includes "Tab" for "Next Window".

What's going on?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Open **dach** :

type keyboard and navigate to **Keyboard**

[image]

This could work if you are using unity 2D

If you want if with effect you should logout and login as 3D

Comment: Thanks Nux for the snapshot, I do have it. My misfortune started after I installed gnome-session-fallback.  At this point, the shortcut (as you pointed out in the snapshot) does look ok. That's why it's very weird.